# How can we draw an arc in python from radius and central angle

Tags: python-3.x, math, geometry

To draw an arc, there are many ways, sometimes using Arc method if we have the center and the radius, or if we have the coordinates of start and end points with the radius as well.

But I have now a case where I have:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVFhM.png)

In the attached link, I have an arc with known radius and central angle which gives us x the length of the chord, no information about the coordinates of the center or the starting or ending point.

Is there a function or method in python, that enables to draw an arc of circle knowing the radius and the angle of curvature (or what we can central angle) ?

Comment: What graphics framework are you using? Tkinter?

Comment: Do you simply want to calculate the length of the chord (`x`) given radius (`R`) and half angle (`θ`)? Note that there is no arc involved in that calculation.  Or do you want to create a plot? Or both?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not enough to have angles and sizes to draw an arc - you need also coordinates of some basic points (center, ends, something else )